# ¿Cómo mandar resultado de función javascript a input text con un button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, function

Cuento con una función Javascript que genera un código aleatorio el cual es el siguiente:

```
   function codigo(){
   var caracteres = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXYZ2346789";
   var folio = "";
   for (i=0; i<20; i++) folio +=caracteres.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*caracteres.length)); 
   }
```

Necesito ahora poder hacer que un botón genere el código aleatorio de esta función pero mostrándola en un campo de texto html cada que se le de click. Esto intentando de la siguiente manera, pero no lo consigo...

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FOLIO" id="folio" name="folio" required>
    <input type="button" value="Generar Folio" onclick='codigo();'>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta asignar el valor con `document.getElementById("folio").value=folio;`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function codigo() {
  var caracteres = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXYZ2346789";
  var folio = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) folio += caracteres.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * caracteres.length));
console.log(folio);
document.getElementById("folio").value=folio;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FOLIO" id="folio" name="folio" required>
  <input type="button" value="Generar Folio" onclick='codigo();'>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias, dios lo bendiga...